# How to only see top result when sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to only show the top result when doing a select query. the single select query below works just fine

```
SELECT AVG(PROD_PRICE) AS Expr1
FROM LGPRODUCT
GROUP BY BRAND_ID
ORDER BY Expr1
```

but when I try

```
SELECT TOP(1)
SELECT AVG(PROD_PRICE) AS Expr1
FROM LGPRODUCT
GROUP BY BRAND_ID
ORDER BY Expr1
```

SQL Server tells me I have an syntax error near the second Select.

I've tried everything I can find. Any ideas?

Comment: that does not really make sense. What are you trying to select?

Comment: If you only want the highest average, why not use function [max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: How about `SELECT TOP(1) AVG(PROD_PRICE) AS Expr1
FROM LGPRODUCT
GROUP BY BRAND_ID
ORDER BY Expr1`

Comment: Can you please try without parenthesis? Like this: SELECT TOP 1 AVG(PROD_PRICE)

Comment: Please, show the code that trows an error, because it is not clear how to add `top(N)` to receive an error

Comment: What is "the second Select" ? I see only one Select .

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1 AVG(PROD_PRICE) AS Expr1 
FROM LGPRODUCT 
GROUP BY BRAND_ID 
ORDER BY Expr1
```

Works for me!

Comment: Yeah that worked! How I didn't try that before I'll never know. Thank you!!

Comment: Please, describe what part of code actually resolves an issue and why, because parenthesized `top(n)` is a [documented syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and ["works" too](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=db1bc48046768f64251f4c99d062d90c). So just "it works" is not very helpful because future readers cannot understand what really works

Comment: Changing my SELECT to SELECT TOP 1 corrected my issue. I was trying SELECT TOP 1 SELECT AVG(PROD_PRICE) The two SELECTs together would be a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
SELECT TOP 1 AVG(PROD_PRICE) AS Expr1
FROM LGPRODUCT
GROUP BY BRAND_ID
ORDER BY Expr1
```

Comment: Please, describe what part of code actually resolves an issue and why, because parenthesized top(n) is a [documented syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and ["works" too](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=db1bc48046768f64251f4c99d062d90c]. So just "it works" is not very helpful because future readers cannot understand what really works

Comment: Changing my SELECT to SELECT TOP 1 corrected my issue. I was trying
SELECT TOP 1
SELECT AVG(PROD_PRICE) 
The two SELECTs together would be a syntax error.